# Getting values from dynamic select boxes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a dynamic select box(s) that generates a unique id with a prefix `childs-age`.

So I have `childs-age-0`, `childs-age-1`, `childs-age-2` and so on depending on how many have been selected.

I have used `{{'child-age-'+$index}}` to generate this.

I need to get the values from the form and put them into an array.

```
childsAges=[2,5,9]
```

This is what I have so far

```
for(var i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
        {
        var childAges = document.getElementById("child-age-" + i);
            angular.forEach(childAges, function(value){
                console.log(childAges.value)
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This is what I have so far ...

Remove all this DOM reading code with `document.getElementById`. This is not Angular way.

You need to use ngModel directives and bind each of new selectbox to the dynamic model. For example:

```
<select ng-model="childAge[$index]">
    <!-- ngOptions or static options ... -->
</select>
```

Then access ages in controller as:

```
$scope.childAges
```

Comment: Ok..got that, but I'm using this in my factory not in my controller so I can't use scope...I'm collecting form data in my factory

Comment: I have already generated the dynamic select boxes...I just need to get the data from each of them in the factory

Comment: var childAge0 = $("#child-age-0").val();
var childAge1 = $("#child-age-1").val();
var childAge2 = $("#child-age-2").val();
var childAge3 = $("#child-age-3").val();

Comment: Are forms usually processed in the controller then to access the scope?